# How to start internet explorer without any add-ons except flash?

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, autoit

I know there is a mode for IE called No-Addons but is it possible to start internet explorer with autoit or similiar tools or in any way with only adobe flash or reversed how to disable spammy toolbars with autoit ?

I know i can create automatizing scripts but the solution should work with windows 7, xp, vista and IE7-8-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the autoit code:

```
    ; Toolbar Kontrolü Başla

  ; 64 bit başla

if $mimari == 64 Then

For $i = 1 to 100 
$var = RegEnumVal("HKLM64\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $i)
If @error <> 0 Then ExitLoop
$read = RegRead("HKLM64\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $var)
$result_no = StringInStr($var, "Locked")
$result_yes = StringInStr($var, "-")
if $result_no == 0 and $result_yes > 0 Then
$result = RegDelete("HKLM64\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $var)
$i = $i-1
EndIf
Next

EndIf   

  ; 64 bit bitir

For $i = 1 to 100 
$var = RegEnumVal("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $i)
If @error <> 0 Then ExitLoop
$read = RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $var)
$result_no = StringInStr($var, "Locked")
$result_yes = StringInStr($var, "-")
if $result_no == 0 and $result_yes > 0 Then
$result = RegDelete("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbar", $var)
$i = $i-1
EndIf
Next

; Toolbar Kontrolü Bitir
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to options in IE and disable whatever you want....

Comment: Yes, tell that to the customers, who are barely capable of finding IE icon.